# Correctness of proof that weak convergence implies pointwise convergence in C([0,1])

Tags: functional-analysis, functions, weak-convergence

I want to prove that in the space of (complex-valued) continuous functions on the real interval [0,1] equipped with the sup norm, which I will denote by $\mathscr{C}([0,1])$, weak convergence implies pointwise convergence.
My reference material uses a proof via the dirac measure, which I don't yet understand. Maybe in addition to checking my proof for correctness, someone could also address my difficulties with the dirac way, which I will state at the end of my post.
In the following, $\mathbb{K}$ will be the underlying field, i.e. $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$.

So let $(f_n)_n\subset\mathscr{C}([0,1])$ such that $f_n \overset{w}\rightarrow f$, where $f \in \mathscr{C}([0,1])$.

This is my proof, and I would like to know whether it is correct:
 For every $y \in [0,1]$, I define the operator $$\Phi_y: span\{f_n-f\lvert n \in \mathbb{N}\} \rightarrow \mathbb{K}$$
$$\sum_{i=1}^{N}\lambda_i(f_i-f) \mapsto \sum_{i=1}^{N}\lambda_i(f_i-f)(y)$$

Then for any functions $g,h$ in the span, and $\mu \in \mathbb{K}$, we have $$\Phi_y(g+\mu h)=\Phi_y\left(\sum_{i=1}^{N_g}\lambda_i^g(f_i-f)+\mu \sum_{i=1}^{N_h}\lambda_i^h(f_i-f)\right)=\Phi_y\left(\sum_{i=1}^{\max\{N_g,N_h\}}(\lambda_i^g+\mu\lambda_i^h)(f_i-f)\right)=\sum_{i=1}^{\max\{N_g,N_h\}}(\lambda_i^g+\mu\lambda_i^h)(f_i-f)(y)=\sum_{i=1}^{\max\{N_g,N_h\}}\lambda_i^g(f_i-f)(y)+\sum_{i=1}^{\max\{N_g,N_h\}}\mu\lambda_i^h(f_i-f)(y)$$$$=\Phi_y(g)+\mu \Phi_y(h)$$ providing linearity.
We also have $$\lvert\Phi_y(g)\rvert=\lvert\sum_{i=1}^{N_g}\lambda_i^g(f_i-f)(y)\rvert\le\sup_{x \in [0,1]}\lvert\sum_{i=1}^{N_g}\lambda_i^g(f_i-f)(x)\rvert=\lvert\lvert g\rvert\rvert_{\infty}$$
So each $\Phi_y$ is linear on the span, which is a subspace of $\mathscr{C}([0,1])$, and also bounded by the norm.
By Hahn-Banach then follows that we have an extension of each $\Phi_y$ on the continuous dual of $\mathscr{C}([0,1])$, and weak convergence gives $$f_n(y)-f(y)=(f_n-f)(y)=\Phi_y(f_n-f)\rightarrow 0$$ for all y in [0,1], which was to be proven.

The alternative proof in my notes goes like this:
$f_n \overset{w}\rightarrow f \implies \forall \text{finite measures on [0,1] with the Borel algebra}: \lvert \int f_n d\mu-\int f d\mu\rvert \rightarrow 0 \overset{\text{dirac measure}}\implies \forall x \in [0,1] \lvert f_n(x)-f(x)\rvert \rightarrow 0$

I do not know what is used in the first step, are all integrals over the whole interval [0,1] over* finite measures continuous functionals? Is there a theorem that says so?

*I do not know whether 'over a measure' is the right expression here.

Comment: Just observe that $\Phi_{y}(f) = f(y)$ is a bounded linear functional on $\mathscr{C}[0,1]$.

Comment: What do you mean? This is basically the essence of my proof, of which I want to know whether it is correct.

Comment: The proof is this simple: Clearly $\Phi_{y}(f)=f(y)$ is a bounded linear functional on $\mathscr{C}[0,1]$. Not must else needs to be said, does it? You don't need to mention measures, integrals or sums at all to conclude that, if $\{ f_n \}$ converges weakly to $f \in \mathscr{C}[0,1]$, then the sequence converges pointwise everywhere to $f$.

Comment: This is exactly what I did in my proof. Did you even read it? I need an extension because the domain of $\Phi_y$ isn't the whole space.

Comment: For each $y \in [0,1]$, $\Phi_{y}$ is defined on all of $\mathscr{C}[0,1]$.

Comment: Sorry, I was confused that you used the same name for another functional. Thank you, this is indeed way shorter. Do you know what exactly is used to get the result by using the dirac measure? I would like to understand the other proof as well.

Comment: The Dirac measure is a way of representing $\Phi_{y}$ as an integral, but you don't need the representation because the point evaluation linear functional is what is being used. If you know the Riemann-Stieltjes integral, every bounded linear functional $\Phi$ on $\mathscr{C}[0,1]$ can be represented as $\Phi(f)=\int_{a}^{b}f(t)d\rho(t)$, where $\rho$ is a function of bounded variation on $[0,1]$; $\rho$ is unique to a constant if normalized so that $\rho(t+0)=\rho(t)$ for $0 < t < 1$. Then $\Phi_{y}$ is represented by $\rho = \chi_{[y,1]}$. Or, you can use Borel measures on $[0,1]$.

Comment: Note: There are special cases in the normalization for $\rho$ at the endpoints.

Comment: I don't know about Riemann-Stieltjes yet, and I see that the proof via point evaluation is way better than the dirac-measure one. I just would like to understand how weak convergence implies that the integrals over each finite measure converge. What property of weak convergence implies that this is so?

Comment: What you may be missing is the Riesz Representation Theorem. If $\Lambda$ is a bounded linear functional on $C[0,1]$ there is a unique complex measure $\mu$ such that $\Lambda f=\int f\,d\mu$ for all $f\in C[0,1]$. (If $\Lambda f=f(y)$ then $\mu$ is a Dirac measure....))

Comment: If you know Borel measures, then every bounded linear function $\Phi$ on $\mathscr{C}[0,1]$ is uniquely represented as $\Phi(f)=\int fd\mu$, where $\mu$ is a complex Borel measure. Therefore, $\{ f_n \}$ converges weakly to $f$ iff $\lim_n \int f_n d\mu = \int fd\mu$ for all complex Borel measures $\mu$. The representation of every bounded linear functional in this way is the original Riesz representation theorem and dates back to around 1910 in the earliest development of Functional Analysis.

Comment: Looks like David and I were posting at the same time.

Comment: Great. This is exactly what I didn't know. And the other direction is also correct, that is: for every finite measure there exists a bounded linear functional with the same property?

Comment: Yes. $|\int fd\mu| \le \|f\|_{\mathscr{C}[0,1]}\|\mu\|$, where $\|\mu\|$ is the total variation of the complex Borel measure. In fact, $\Phi_{\mu}(f)=\int fd\mu$ has norm exactly equal to $\|\Phi_{\mu} \|=\|\mu\|$.

Comment: So I have isometry on top of everything. Good to know about this theorem, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was pointed out to me in the comments, the easiest way to go about proving the claim is to consider the family of functionals $\Phi_y: \mathscr{C}([0,1])\rightarrow\mathbb{K}$, $g \mapsto g(y)$ where [0,1] is the index set.

The pointwise definition of both addition of functions and multiplication of a function by a scalar immediately gives linearity, and the boundedness of each operator follows directly from having equipped the space with the sup norm.

Weak convergence then gives $\forall y:f_n(y)-f(y)=(f_n-f)(y)=\Phi_y(f_n-f)\rightarrow 0$